# Retrofit 2 send an empty array

Tags: java, retrofit2

I'm sending an array of integers to the backend via this Retrofit interface:

```java
@PATCH("save/ids")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Output> saveIds(@Field("ids[]") List<Integer> ids);
```

Now this works when I have an `ArrayList` with some items.
But to reset all the ids the servers wants an empty array called `ids`.
When I send an empty array, Retrofit doesn't send the array - it just drops the parameter.

I create my `ArrayList` as follows:

```java
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (FooObjects object : listOfIds) {
    if (object.isEnabled()) {
        ids.add(object.getId());
    }
}
```

How can I send an empty array anyway?

Comment: What is _exact_ payload of the list you're going to send? Something like `ids=[1,2,3]` and `ids=[]` respectively?

Comment: It should be ids=[] but because the ids array is empty retrofit doesn't send ids=[].

Comment: So you seem to have expectations.: in fact, Retrofit will send `ids[]=foo&ids[]=bar&ids[]=baz`, not `ids[]=[foo,bar,baz]`.

Comment: I had same problem, and did not find any proper solution. if that list is empty sending RequestBody with with empty value  worked.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to change the setting on the Gson converter so it serializes nulls - this will then send `"ids":[]`, as you wish.

Create a new Gson instance using the GsonBuilder with serializeNulls():

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

You can then pass this to the retrofit builder when you are setting up your retrofit instance:

```
private Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
```

Extensive configuration options are available, and listed in the Gson documentation: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation I managed to deal with it by telling the backend developer which im working with to accept a list contains an empty string and he will deal with it as empty list and it worked fine with me
just made simple condition in the parameter of the service

```
if(list.isEmpty()) listOf(“”) else list
```