# How to send empty HashMap in Retrofit request POST request android

Tags: android, request, hashmap, http-post, retrofit

trying to send empty `HashMap` in `post` request but retrofit omits empty `HashMap`.
how can I make this `HashMap` as required that it must be serialized and post in the request.

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216394/retrofit-2-send-an-empty-array) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671097/retrofit-post-request-sends-null-object) but no luck

made custom exclude strategy like this:

```
val gsonNullSupport = GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(object :
                ExclusionStrategy {
                override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
                override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            }).create()
val gsonNullSupportConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonNullSupport)

retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(gsonNullSupportConverterFactory)
```

and also tried this:

```
val gsonNullSupport = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

            val gsonNullSupportConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonNullSupport)

retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(gsonNullSupportConverterFactory)
```

but still unable to send `empty` `HashMap` or `null` `HashMap` in request. need help.